# Declare JScript variables by array and for loop

Tags: javascript, html

There is some part of my code that gives me headaches. I've missed something. I want to create, declare variables by array but it won't work. It works fine when I declare them manually (like am1=1; am2=2;...). But the problem is when I try the for loop and to create variables that way.

There is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/b3Mr7/3/) of my problem

**myhtml.html**

```
1.Question:<br/>
<textarea name="question11" ></textarea><br/><div id="inner1"></div><button type="button" onClick="addmore1();">Add more</button>
<br/><br/>
2.Question:<br/>
<textarea name="question21" ></textarea><br/><div id="inner2"></div><button type="button" onClick="addmore2();">Add more</button>
```

**myscript.js**

```
var am = [];
for(var i=1; i<3; i++){
  am[i] = 1;
}

function addmore1() {
        am1++;
        n=1;
        var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
        textarea.name = "question" + n + am1;
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = textarea.outerHTML;
        document.getElementById("inner"+n).appendChild(div);
}

function addmore2() {
        am2++;
        n=2;
        var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
        textarea.name = "question" + n + am2;
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = textarea.outerHTML;
        document.getElementById("inner"+n).appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: You are not even trying to access the array `am` in your functions. [Learn the basics about arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object).

Comment: A variable is a label *you* have given something. A program that declares its own variables would be a program for writing programs, and is rarely what you want. Usually what you actually want is just to add or access members of an array, but I'm not clear what you're actually trying to create here.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the same thing as am1=1; am2=1; When you put this in my fiddle instead of array and for loop, it works great, but I want to make it through a for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b3Mr7/4/) with the fix for your problem.

If you look at the developer console (F12 in most browsers), you can see the error: am1 and am2 are undefined.

I guess what you meant to do is to refer to `am[1]` instead of `am1`. Althought the code is working after that change, there is a lot of room for improvement: you could reuse more code by having only one `addmore` function, etc . e.g.:

```
function addmore(index) {
        am[index]++;
        var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
        textarea.name = "question" + index + am[index];
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = textarea.outerHTML;
        document.getElementById("inner"+index).appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: Wow. This improvement seems to be incredible. But I cannot implemet it really well, can u do the fiddle just to see how it works on my example.

Comment: just updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b3Mr7/7/ (take a look at the function invocation in the html)

Comment: This is the proper solution that I was seeking for. Thanx

Answer (score 1):

if you are declaring them by array, why aren't you using them by array?

```
var am = [];
for(var i=1; i<3; i++){
  am[i] = 1;
}

function addmore1() {
    am[1]++;
    n=1;
    var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textarea.name = "question" + n + am[1];
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = textarea.outerHTML;
    document.getElementById("inner"+n).appendChild(div);
}

function addmore2() {
    am[2]++;
    n=2;
    var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textarea.name = "question" + n + am[2];
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = textarea.outerHTML;
    document.getElementById("inner"+n).appendChild(div);
}
```

or am I missing something?

Answer (score -1):

You must use `.push()` to add values to an array.

`var am = [];
for(i=1; i<3; i++){
  am.push(1);
}`

Sorry if I didn't answer your question completely.

Comment: No, `am[i] = 1` is a perfect valid way to set array elements. `.push` is not necessary.